# How can I show entered password using tooltip on input type=password in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display the "Password entered by the user" on the tooltip placed on the input element `type=password`, only if the "Show Password" checkbox is selected. ?

what I am trying to achive is.

if user checks the checkbox "Show Password"
then the password should be visible in the plaintext using the tooltip.

so far I have done like this.

**HTML**

```
<form> 
    <span class="form-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Password" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="show-password" onClick="javascript:showPassword(this)">Show Password</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showPassword(obj) {
    if (obj.checked) {
        /* checkmark is checked*/

        /*show tooltip*/
        $('#password').tooltip('show');

        /*create onkeyup event so the tooltip changes as the password changes.*/
        $("#password").keyup(function () {
            var entered_password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            $("#password").attr("title", entered_password);
            $("#password").tooltip('fixTitle');
        });
    } else {
        //hide the tooltip//
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/834Nj/1/**

so far its only working if I select and reselect the checkbox but not as I type the password.

Comment: You don't need to listen `keyup` event in your case. Listen `change` event instead

Comment: It should not possible. It poses security risk.

Comment: It doesn't pose a security risk. In newer versions of IE there is a little button that allows you to reveal your typed password. On most WiFi login screens there is a check box to show the password in plain text. It shouldn't be enabled by default, but if the user wants to reveal their own password thats their choice.

Comment: May I just ask, why on a tooltip hover? Every site I've seen that has this feature changes the password box itself into plain text and back. Why go against the norm, is there a good reason for it?

Comment: @hindmost thanks , looking in to it.

Comment: @setek i tried to implement that too but, found its not possible to change the input type using javascript from password to text, even created 2 input one is type=password and another is type=text, where type=text is hidden by default, but which value should i catch using php? moreover, it will show both inputs if javascript is disabled, so the only option left for me to use tooltip unless you have some other working method which works in most browsers.

Comment: @AMB I could do exactly that? Also, other people have been able to, so that means it's possible :) If that's exactly what you're after, maybe edit your question with that code instead?

Comment: I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/834Nj/4/, simply changing the input type.

Comment: @setek kickass.to guys are doing it, so prolly ill create a new question.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin i didnt know iys possible, if it works in most browsers then you sir deserv more upvotes. thanks, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @AMB, well I did similar thing for my projects. It looks crappy in IE11, cause it has its own "eye" icon, which shows password no matter what your checkbox value is. So maybe you should consider that.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin just checked its not working in firefox, i guess its because the security reason. or i messed something up.,

Comment: @AMB - strange, fiddle works fine on my machine. I have version 31.0

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin sorry my bad, local copy didnt had http for cdn jquery., now its working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do It like this :

```
$("#show-password").on('change' , function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#password').tooltip({title : $('#password').val(), placement:'right',trigger:'manual'});
    $('#password').tooltip('show');
  }
  else{
    $('#password').tooltip('destroy');
  }
})

$('#password').on('keyup' , function(){

  if($('#show-password').is(':checked')){
    $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.title = $(this).val();
    $(this).data('bs.tooltip').options.animation = false;
    $(this).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');

    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    }
  }   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/834Nj/7/

Comment: according to the question , this is the best answer, but if someone is trying to show the enetered password in the same field then Ilya Luzyanin made this http://jsfiddle.net/834Nj/4/